# How can I run code that my Python program stored in a string?

Tags: python, urlopen, pastebin

So, im trying to make a script that takes code from a pastebin post and runs it. But, for some reason it doesnt run the code. I dont know why. Could someone explain why this wont work so i can fix the issue?

I tried:
(dont mind the imports im gonna use those for later)

```
import os 
from json import loads, dumps
from base64 import b64decode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def get_code():
  test = 'None'
  try:
    test = urlopen(Request('https://pastebin.com/raw/4dnZntN3')).read().decode()
  except:
    pass
  return test

test = get_code()

def main():
  test

main()
```

The output is empty, and no errors.

Comment: You never print anything. It probably does something, but you have no way of seeing it

Comment: `def main(): test` definitely does not do what you think it does. `test` is just a `str` object that happens to be [probably] a python code. Still. it's just a string. It's same if it was `def main(): 'print("3"+"2")'`

Comment: The pastebin post contains the code "print("3"+"2")".

Comment: The content of the pastebin post is irrelevant. If you want to print output to stdout, you have to call functions like `print()` in your code.

Comment: A Stack Overflow's title should be _specific to that individual question_. Don't refer to "this"; spend the title space to describe what "this" is.

Comment: Downloading and running some arbitrary code from the internet seems like a security risk and generally just a bad idea

Comment: @buran Any way i can solve this? As i said, im fairly new to python.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function instead of just printing test
use exec(test)

```
def main():
    exec(test)
```

Answer (score -2):

you are printing nothing and 'return test' wont be ran because it is outside of the try block

Comment: The things outside the try block still run after the try block completes.

Comment: The pastebin post contains the code:
print("3"+"2"), so i thought it would print 32 but it didnt.